# Cannot rename the first column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have been using `pandas` for some years, but have never seen this behavior. I use version `0.18.1`. I have a `.csv` file with the following content:

```
id;foo;bar
100001;11-22;spam
100002;22-33;spamspam
```

I'm reading it into a DataFrame:

```
pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep=';', index_col=False, encoding='UTF-8')
```

This is what I get:

```
      id    foo       bar
0  100001  11-22      spam
1  100002  22-33  spamspam
```

Now I'd like to rename the `id` field into `new_id`:

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={'id': 'new_id'}, inplace=True)
```

However, it leaves the `id` column with the same name.

The `id` column is present in the `df.columns`:

```
df.columns
Index([u'id', u'foo', u'bar'], dtype='object')
```

And its index is:

```
df.index
Index([u'0', u'1'], dtype='object')
```

Trying to rename the `foo` or `bar` columns works as expected:

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={'foo': 'new_foo'}, inplace=True)

      id new_foo       bar
0  100001   11-22      spam
1  100002   22-33  spamspam
```

I thought that it may be something special about the `id` keyword, however the same behavior can be observed by renaming the `id` column into something else. **How to I rename the first column in the data frame?**

Comment: It seems first column is converted to `index`, `pd.read_csv(csv_path, sep=';', index_col=False, encoding='UTF-8').reset_index()` should help.

Comment: You can also check `print (df.columns)` if there is `id`

Comment: Or there is some trailng whitespace, check `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: @jezrael, thanks. Posted the printed results in the question body.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov: Did you inspect `df.columns.tolist()`? I vaguely recall an instance where looking at `df.columns` did not reveal the problem...

Comment: Another thing you might try is inspecting the CSV as bytes: `open(csv_path, 'rb').read(10)`. If you see a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), for instance, then change the encoding to `'utf-8-sig'`.

Comment: @unutbu, bingo! That was the problem - my .csv file had `utf8-bom` encoding. Using the `'utf-8-sig'` does not help, however, changing the encoding of the file manually to UTF-8 did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like weird bug, you can assign new columns names:

```
df.columns = ['new_id'] + df.columns.tolist()[1:]
print (df)
   new_id    foo       bar
0  100001  11-22      spam
1  100002  22-33  spamspam
```

In pandas 0.23.4 `rename` with `id` working nice.

If problem with `BOM` it was resolved in [pandas 0.19.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4793#issuecomment-276644325).

Possible solution is change `encoding` in your pandas version:

```
df = csv_path, sep=';', index_col=False, encoding='UTF-16')
```

Comment: The problem was with the `BOM` encoding. Using 'utf-8-sig' or 'UTF-16' does not help. Had to change the encoding of the file manually to `UTF-8`. Works fine then!

Answer (score 1):

I did same thing on same data. It's work fine for me. So not able to find bug.
But can tell another option which you may already known.

```
df.columns = ['new_id', 'foo', 'bar']
```