# How to rename the first column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have come across this question many a times over internet however not many answers are there except for few of the likes of the following:

[Cannot rename the first column in pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386090/cannot-rename-the-first-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

I approached the same using following:

```
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Column1'})
```

Is there a better or cleaner way of doing the rename of the first column of a pandas dataframe? Or any specific column number?

Answer (score 7):

You're already using a *cleaner* way in pandas.

It is sad that:

```
df.columns[0] = 'Column1'
```

Is impossible because `Index` objects do not support mutable assignments. It would give an `TypeError`.

You still could do iterable unpacking:

```
df.columns = ['Column1', *df.columns[1:]]
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_axis(['Column1', *df.columns[1:]], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for pitching in @U12-Forward. If the mutable assignments were possible, the first option would have been the cleanest/ easiest one to follow. Thanks for suggesting the iterable unpacking! It for sure adds more depth to how one can handle the dataframe!

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism Yeap! this should be the shortest option! :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if cleaner, but possible idea is convert to list and set by indexing new value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[4,7,0,2])

arr = df.columns.tolist()
arr[0] = 'Column1'
df.columns = arr


print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Column1, 7, 0, 2]
Index: []
```

Comment: That's indeed one good intuitive way to do it @jezrael!

Comment: This doesn't work for mixed type columns, if the original columns where numeric this wouldn't work @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism

Comment: @jezrael it gives `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Column1'`

Comment: @jezrael Sorry I meant if the columns are all integers

Comment: @jezrael if the columns are all intgers, try it

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism Yes.

Comment: U12-Forward is right @jezrael. It does give error if the column was all numeric

Comment: @JALO-JusAnotherLivngOrganism - yop, agree, so list is better here.

Answer (score 1):

As as a one liner

```
df.columns.values[0] = 'Column1'
```